# Sequential #id to pass to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have various form with sequential id, and I'm trying to code a ajax function which could analyze id and call the proper PHP function. But obviously jQuery is having a problem about getting the right id.

I think code will explain better:

js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var num= /\d/

    $('#delete'+num).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // evito di far ricaricare la pagina dopo aver effettuato il submit

        $.post(
            my_vars.ajaxurl,
            {
                action : 'delete_bird',         
                id : form.find('input[name=id]').val(),
                user_id : form.find('input[name=user_id]').val(),
                table : form.find('input[name=table]').val()
            },
            function( response ) {
                 // qualcosa da eseguire se la richiesta è andata a buon fine
            }
         );            
    });             
});
```

The form created in a php file:

```
<form method='post' id='delete".$results[$j][0]."'>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value=".$results[$j][0]." />
        <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value=".$results[$j][1]." />
        <input type='hidden' name='table' value=".$table_RapaciTelefono." />
        <input type='submit' value='Cancella' />
</form>
```

I hope I've been clear.

Comment: so where is it getting stuck? did you check the console for errors or the network tab?

Comment: Rather than using regex in the selector, what about using a selector that starts with #delete? Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Give the form a class and then tell "jquary" to select all elements with that class. Or is your question a different one?

Comment: So yeah. First, the regex in the selector isn't going to do what you want. Second, the form variable you refer to in your ajax call has never been declared. Third, which ID are you trying to refer to -- the div's ID or the form element NAMED id? Fourth, using the name 'id' for a field is going to confuse the crap out of other developers who may have to try to follow you.

Comment: Sorry, I've just done a copy-paste form a tutorial iwth some edit that I could understan. Obiously was a bad Idea. I never user ajax or jquery before. Anyway, I found that your regex was exactly what i needed so thank you, anyway, obviuosly now it doesnt work as well for the second point you made. 

the variable form should refer to the form with the ID defined by this.

third point: I'm refering to the form ID (the attribute)

For the forth point, you are right and I will change variables' name after i have fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('[id^="delete"').on( 'submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // evito di far ricaricare la pagina dopo aver effettuato il submit
    var form = $(this);

    $.post(
     my_vars.ajaxurl,
     {
        action : 'delete_bird',         
        id : form.find('input[name=id]').val(),
        user_id : form.find('input[name=user_id]').val(),
        table : form.find('input[name=table]').val()
     },

     function( response ) {
            // qualcosa da eseguire se la richiesta è andata a buon fine
     }
  );            
 });             
});
```